# Quadratic equation: negative discriminant in C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm sorry if this question is very simple, but I'm new to C++. I'm designing a program that calculates 2 roots using the quadratic formula. However, my program doesn't work when my discriminant is a negative number.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C++
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int pointa;
    int pointb;
    int pointc;
    int discriminant1;
    float root1;
    float root2;

    cout << "Please enter a, b and c: ";
    cin >> pointa;
    cin >> pointb;
    cin >> pointc;

    discriminant1 = (pow(pointb, 2)) - (4 * pointa * pointc);

    root1 = (-(pointb) + sqrt(discriminant1)) / (2 * pointa);
    root2 = (-(pointb) - sqrt(discriminant1)) / (2 * pointa);

    cout << "Root1 :" << root1 << endl;
    cout << "Root2 :" << root2 << endl;
    return 0;
```

The main problem is the input for `pointb`. Is there any way to force `pointb` to become a positive number when squaring the input, much like adding parentheses in a TI-84? When inputting a number like -1, it causes the whole formula to become invalid.

Comment: Does [abs()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/) work?

Comment: Aside: you should review the pitfalls of using `pow` with integer types.

Comment: Why should a negative `pointb` make the expression invalid? The formula only results in complex numbers if the *discriminant* is negative.

Comment: You could change to `complex<double>` instead of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the absolute value you can use [`abs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/) from the `<cstdlib>` header.

However, as I learned it, if the discriminant is negative, it simply means that there is no solution.

So it might be better solution to just add an `if` clause to only execute that part of the formula if the discrimant is positive.

In more advanced maths, the square root of a negative number does have an answer in the complex plane. To obtain this result, you can use the datatype `complex<double>` and use the overloaded version of `sqrt()` that takes a complex number.

Comment: Actually, when the determinant is negative there is a solution in the complex plane. In this case you use `complex<double>` to obtain the result. It will have a real and an imaginary components.